# Patches in subversion stable branch

Tags: svn, version-control, repository-pattern

suppose I would like to setup a similar SCM method for my project:

> trunk -> unstable development with new features, internally released every tot.
>
> stable 1.0.x -> feature freeze
>      tag 1.0.1 -> patch release
>      tag 1.0.2 -> patch release

suppose I have to do a patch for 1.0.x and then (of course) have it in the trunk too.

- Should I do the patch in the stable branch or in the trunk?
- What's the best way to port the patches between the trunk->stable or viceversa? 
  (should I merge a single-revision using cherry-picking, or can I regularly merge stable into trunk, or else)?

it is a common pattern, but I would like to know a good and not time-expensive way to handle the stable branch!

Answer (score 4):

presumably trunk has new features not wanted in stable, so it's easier to merge from stable to trunk rather than the other way around. If the affected file(s) haven't been modified in trunk then it doesn't matter which way you do it. If trunk has been completely refactored then obviously merging won't work at all.